# MySQL GROUP BY REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get a comprehensive list of abbreviations that are used in fields of my MySQL table `translations`.
This is how the entries of my table might look like

```
  -english-               -german-

to hit sb.          |   jmd. schlagen
so. stole my bike   |   jd. hat mein Fahrrad gestohlen
I am tall           |   ich bin gross
to see sb.          |   jmd. sehen
1, 2, 3, etc.       |   1, 2, 3, usw.
tree                |   Baum
                   ...
```

Using the MySQL SELECT query `SELECT english FROM translations WHERE english REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]' GROUP BY english` I can show all rows that contain an abbriviation, i.e.

```
  -english-               -german-

to hit sb.          |   jmd. schlagen
so. stole my bike   |   jd. hat mein Fahrrad gestohlen
to see sb.          |   jmd. sehen
1, 2, 3, etc.       |   1, 2, 3, usw.
                   ...
```

The results are grouped, so there are no two rows with identical content of field `english` being displayed. Multiple occurences of an abbreviation are listed seperately, however, i.e. `sb.` appears twice. Due to the great number of rows in `translations` (some ten million), there are too many occurences of common abbreviations like `sb.` or `sth.` so that it gets incredibly time-consuming to create a list of different abbreviations.

I am wondering if there's a way to group by the occurence of a REGEXP pattern as in e.g.  `SELECT english FROM translations WHERE english REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]' GROUP BY english REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]'`

I only need to compose this list once which is why I am working in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Perfect example for third normal form.

Comment: Fix your design. Normalize to 3rd normal, as Mike B suggested, and then your problem essentially goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Good advice re 3rd normal form, but for a quickie, I'd try something like:

```
SELECT
  reverse(substring(reverse(english)
          , locate('.', reverse(english))
          , locate(' ', concat(reverse(english), ' '), locate('.', reverse(english))) - locate('.', reverse(english))
          )) AS abbr
FROM translations
WHERE english LIKE '%.%'
GROUP BY abbr
```

This reverses the string so `abbr.` becomes `.rbba`, then looks for a dot and the first space after the dot (we concat a space at the beginning (now the end) in case there isn't one. Now you have a value to group by.

This will only find the last abbr. in the field.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2e1b/11/0